# Show zero in string grouped value

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, grouping

I'm trying to filter an sql table something like this:

```
| status     | name   | description       |  
|------------|--------|-------------------|  
| finished   | task 1 | finished task 1   |  
| finished   | task 2 | finished task 2   |  
| in_process | task 3 | in process task 1 |
```

but, the status column could have 3 distinct values: `finished`, `in_process` and `new`
the problem: some values could doesn't have records, so how can I have a grouped query with all posible status values?

There is my current query:

```sql
select status, count(status)
from tasks
group by status
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Comment: @GMB done my friend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to list all possible status values, and then bring the table with `left join`.

For example:

```
select s.status, count(t.status) no_status
from (
    select 'finished' status
    union all select 'in_process'
    union all select 'new'
) s
left join mytable t on t.status = s.status
group by s.status
```

Some databases have neater way to declare the derived table of status, like the `values()` table constructor:

```
select s.status, count(t.status) no_status
from (values ('finished'), ('in_process'), ('new')) s(status)
left join mytable t on t.status = s.status
group by s.status
```

You may also use `select distinct` to get the values directly from the table (although this is less efficient, since this requires an additional scan of the original table, and deduplication):

```
select s.status, count(t.status) no_status
from (select distinct status from mytable) s
left join mytable t on t.status = s.status
group by s.status
```

In an ideal situation, you would have a referential table to store all possible status values, say `statuses(status)`:

```
select s.status, count(t.status) no_status
from statuses s
left join mytable t on t.status = s.status
group by s.status
```